# Convert 2D array into RGB image in a loop in Python

Tags: python, image, scipy

I want to convert a 2-dimensional array into an image in python using scipy.misc. Following is an example what I want to achieve

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import toimage, imsave

L = 20      # one side of lattice
N = L*L     # number of sites in the lattice
xs = np.zeros((L,L), float)

x = []
for n in range(100):
    for i in range(L):
        for j in range(L):
            xs[i,j] = np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.9)
            x.append(xs)
```

In this code, for each n value I get a 2D array of xs which I am storing in list x. Instead of storing 2D array xs for each n in x, how can I convert it to an Colour RGB Image, where each value of x between 0.1 and 0.9 would be denoted by different colours ?

Comment: for doing that you need a conversion table (maybe a LUT). How do you pretend to do the conversion? If you have, for example, `xs = 0.3`, to which RGB value will correspond?

Comment: Lets say xs<0.5 will correspond to blue colour and xs>0.5 to red color. I have never done such conversion before. Or may be we could use a gradient of colour from lower value to higher values of xs

Comment: There are infinite ways of converting 1D values to 3D values (The same as saying grey image to RGB image). If you want to code your own method, that is up to your creativity. If not, you have to look for libraries implementing such functions. As a start, you may read about the cv2.cvtColor() function of the OpenCV library...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I asked this question because I do not have an idea  about data matrix to image conversion and how to do it and how to put it in a question properly. Thanks I will check OpenCV library.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

L = 20      # one side of lattice
N = L*L     # number of sites in the lattice
xs = np.zeros((L, L), float)

for n in range(100):
    for i in range(L):
        for j in range(L):
            xs[i,j] = np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.9)
            plt.imshow(xs)
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig('temp.png')
```